# why tomcat is faster than nodejs serving static resource

Tags: java, node.js, performance, express, tomcat

I was told that tomcat is slow when serving static resource, such as js/css/img. (I only familiar with nodejs)

I don't get why tomcat is slower than nodejs/nginx. Should they all use memory-cache, or at least use non-blocking io when serving static resources?

---

I did an AB test and the result is unexpected (tomcat is faster than nodejs). I was using Windows 7 Pro with Intel Core i5-5200 @ 2.20GHz and 8GB RAM (Dell notebook). My nodejs version is v8.9.0 and java version is 1.8.045 and tomcat 5.5.17.

The nodejs code:

```
const path = require('path');
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const staticServer = require('koa-static');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

app.use(staticServer( path.join(__dirname, 'static')) );
app.listen(8001);
```

The nodejs result is:

```
E:\soft-new\apache\Apache24\bin>ab -c 20 -n 1000 http://localhost:8001/benu_crm/a.html
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1748469 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8001

Document Path:          /benu_crm/a.html
Document Length:        3 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   0.679 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      209000 bytes
HTML transferred:       3000 bytes
Requests per second:    1472.67 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       13.581 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.679 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          300.57 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.2      0       1
Processing:     6   13   3.0     13      26
Waiting:        6   11   2.7     10      23
Total:          6   13   3.0     13      26

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     13
  66%     14
  75%     15
  80%     15
  90%     18
  95%     20
  98%     21
  99%     23
 100%     26 (longest request)
```

and the tomcat result is: (for tomcat I simply made a a.html without any java code)

```
E:\soft-new\apache\Apache24\bin>ab -c 20 -n 1000 http://localhost:8050/benu_crm/a.html
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1748469 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8050

Document Path:          /benu_crm/a.html
Document Length:        3 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   0.171 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      222000 bytes
HTML transferred:       3000 bytes
Requests per second:    5847.61 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3.420 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.171 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1267.74 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.2      0       2
Processing:     0    3   1.3      3       8
Waiting:        0    3   1.4      3       8
Total:          0    3   1.3      3       8

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      3
  66%      4
  75%      4
  80%      4
  90%      5
  95%      6
  98%      6
  99%      7
 100%      8 (longest request)
```

---

@EugèneAdell thank you. I increased the size of `a.html` to 309,344 bytes. Then the tomcat 5.5.17 and the nodejs koa2 were nearly equal. I will try NIO tomcat later and put the result too. But it still surprised me than BIO tomcat is nearly equal with koa2.

**nodejs result:**

```
E:\soft-new\apache\Apache24\bin>ab -c 20 -n 1000 http://localhost:8001/benu_crm/a.html
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1748469 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8001

Document Path:          /benu_crm/a.html
Document Length:        309344 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   1.071 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      309555000 bytes
HTML transferred:       309344000 bytes
Requests per second:    933.65 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       21.421 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.071 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          282243.05 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.3      0       3
Processing:     8   21  12.0     20     386
Waiting:        2   10   2.2      9      23
Total:          8   21  12.0     20     386

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     20
  66%     22
  75%     23
  80%     23
  90%     25
  95%     26
  98%     29
  99%     31
 100%    386 (longest request)
```

**tomcat result:**

```
E:\soft-new\apache\Apache24\bin>ab -c 20 -n 1000 http://localhost:8050/benu_crm/a.html
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1748469 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8050

Document Path:          /benu_crm/a.html
Document Length:        309344 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   0.916 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      309573000 bytes
HTML transferred:       309344000 bytes
Requests per second:    1091.64 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       18.321 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.916 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          330021.72 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.4      0       1
Processing:     4   18   3.6     17      45
Waiting:        0    2   2.8      1      22
Total:          4   18   3.6     18      45

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     18
  66%     18
  75%     19
  80%     19
  90%     21
  95%     23
  98%     27
  99%     37
 100%     45 (longest request)
```

Comment: Did you do any benchmark proving this ?

Comment: Modern Tomcat versions use Java NIO and should be pretty similar in performance to native code.  But, as @EugèneAdell says you should verify that in your own environment.

Comment: Your question is far too vague and far too broad. Update your post with the **specific problem** you are trying to resolve. If you just want to gain more insight into Tomcat performance when serving static resources your question is off topic.

Comment: @Eugène Adell   Okey, I will do the test with AB and put the result back later.

Comment: @stdunbar, I editted the post and put the test result, please check. Thanks. I even changed the title because when serving static resources, tomcat was much faster than nodejs koa2 static middleware in my test.

Comment: @stdunbar As we see from the test, he is running Tomcat 5.5 which is not NIO (the NIO connector came with 6.0).

Comment: @jiajianrong You are serving a 3 bytes file, which is very small. Your test doesn't exactly compare the time taken to serve static resources, but more probably the time to establish the TCP connection and to start serving anything.

Comment: Thank you @Eugène Adell, I increased the size of html and now tomcat5 and koa2 were nearly equal. I will test tomcat NIO mode later.

Comment: @jiajianrong If the difference is, as I said in answer, in the "accept connection" part, the biggest the file you will serve, the less difference you will see.

Comment: After the update your post makes even less sense. In one sentence you state **_I don't get why tomcat is slower than nodejs/nginx_** and two sentences later you state **_tomcat is faster than nodejs_**. If you just want to have a discussion about the relative performance of different web servers this post is off topic for SO. **What is your specific question?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With credits to the [tomcat-users](http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users) mailing list and to devshed for this [benchmark](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/braindump/tomcat-benchmark-procedure/), the good Tomcat performance is more likely to be attributed to the Java run-time :

> How is it possible for pure-Java Tomcat to serve static resource
>   faster than Apache httpd ? The main reason we can think of: because
>   Tomcat is written in Java and because Java bytecode can be natively
>   compiled and highly optimized at runtime, well-written Java code can
>   run very fast when it runs on a mature Java VM that implements many
>   runtime optimizations, such as the Sun Hotspot JVM. After it runs and
>   serves many requests, the JVM knows how to optimize it for that
>   particular use on that particular hardware. On the other hand, Apache
>   httpd  is written in C, which is completely compiled ahead of runtime.

However, as your test is about accessing a small file many times, it also could be that the Tomcat's *design* is more efficient than the Node.js' one, particularly for the "accept connection and start serving" part. A network capture would maybe help to see from where comes this latency in Node.js